# Modifying another user registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Here is the problem.

I need to run a Windows Service which is being configured through registry.
Is there any way to modify another user HKCU without enumeration all the users on the machine?

Comment: I know user's login and password. Can I get SID using them?

Comment: I can not find a way to get SID  by hToken (returned by LogonUser).

Comment: I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446670. This method is working but returning sometihng strange. After calling ConvertSidToStringSid I've got string which can not be found in my computer registry.  Do yuo know the reason?

Comment: The registry hive of the other user may not be loaded if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Why not? As far as I understood subkeys in HKEY_USERS are the symbolic links to HKCU for another users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found good way to do it through WMI interface.
I've opened connectioin to WMI (see there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Next, I've enumerated all the items in Win32_Account database.
Each item in win32_Account have Domain, Name and SID fields.

That's the way to get correct SID.

Unfortunately, I still don't know how to make this operation without enumerating all the users.

Also, this method enumerates all the users in domain (even if they never log on to local machine).